# How does one build a new X11 3D driver?

Tags: 3d, x11, linux-device-driver, xorg, mesa

I was wondering why there is no X11 driver for the mali 3D arm gfx chip.  I looked into building an X11 driver for the available kernel driver, but could not find any documentation on how to build an X11 3D driver.  There exists only the minimal amount of documentation about how to build projects like DRI and Mesa, but no documentation about how to contribute or exand those projects.

Is there any documentation about how to start developing a hardware accelerated 3D driver for Xorg?

Comment: Your main problem is likely to be lack of specs on the Mali hardware, rather than figuring out how to do a driver.

Answer (score 3):

1) x.org, freedesktop.org

2) dri-devel@lists.freedesktop.org, xorg-devel@lists.freedesktop.org

3) irc.freenode.org #dri-devel #xorg-devel

Of course, we're going to say the same thing, which is "We don't have docs on Mali, and don't know anybody that does, so your task is going to be time-consuming and arduous." But you should talk to us anyway, since we love talking to new developers.

~ C.